# How to retrieve specific JSON value from a column containing a JSON array

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this JSON array in a SQL Server table:

```
[
    {
        "FieldName": "DateCreated",
        "FieldValue": "10/22/2020"
    },
    {
        "FieldName": "IsMember",
        "FieldValue": "false"
    },
    {
        "FieldName": "EntityId",
        "FieldValue": "ABC123"
    }
]
```

I want to fetch only the `FieldValue` of the `EntityId` object, so the output should be only `ABC123`.

I have this query

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(JsonColumnData, '$[2].FieldValue') AS EntityId
FROM MyTable
```

This returns the `EntityId` value, but the thing is that I have no guarantee that the `EntityId` will always be in the same position of the JSON array.

Is it possible to have the select return the `EntityId` regardless of its position in the JSON array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [OPENJSON()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) to query the data and just filter the row(s) that contain EntityId...

```sql
create table dbo.MyTable (
  JsonColumnData nvarchar(max)
);

insert dbo.MyTable (JsonColumnData) values (N'[
    {
        "FieldName": "DateCreated",
        "FieldValue": "10/22/2020"
    },
    {
        "FieldName": "IsMember",
        "FieldValue": "false"
    },
    {
        "FieldName": "EntityId",
        "FieldValue": "ABC123"
    }
]');

select FieldValue as EntityId
from dbo.MyTable
cross apply openjson(JsonColumnData) with (
  FieldName nvarchar(11),
  FieldValue nvarchar(11)
)
where FieldName = N'EntityId';
```

Which yields...

```
EntityId
---------
ABC123
```